# Is there a way to make this query faster

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this query and it runs in like 0.5s I need it to be faster is there a way to make this happen

```
$events_id = Event::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
->select("id")
->orderByDesc('id')->pluck('id');

$total_visitors_count = Visitor::select(DB::raw('count(*) as num_visits'))
->join('event_visitor', 'visitors.id', '=', 'event_visitor.visitor_id')
->whereIn('event_visitor.event_id', $events_id)
->count();
```

Comment: I'd say 0.5 secs is already pretty fast.

Comment: i'd suggest that you make your relationships with Eloquent model.

you have oneToMany between User and `Event`, and you have manyToMany between `Event` and `Visitor` using `event_visitor` as pivot

Comment: You are doing two independent queries. You should combine them into a single query instead.

Comment: Why you need `join`,why not just `count(visitor_id)` on table `event_visitor`, and make sure you have index on `event_visitor.event_id`

Answer (score 0):

Relationships in laravel are a good way to keep our queries simple and fast, you can make relations between your entities to handle this:

User model class:

```php
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}
```

Event model class:

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function visitors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Visitor::class, 'event_visitor');
}
```

Visitor model class:

```php
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'event_visitor');
}
```

now, your queries become like this:

```php
$events_id = auth()->user()->events()->orderByDesc('id')->pluck('id');

$total_visitors_count = Visitor::with('events')
    ->whereHas('events', fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('id', $events_id))
    ->count();
```